# Why doesn't Latex automatically hyphenate a word for me

Tags: latex

Why doesn't Latex  **automatically** hyphenate a word for me

```latex
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Why doesn't Latex  hyphenate a word for me? The words aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa goes beyond the boundary like this.
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't Latex  hyphenate a word for me? The words aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa goes beyond the boundary like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latex can only hyphenate words for which its knows how to hyphenate them. If you encounter a word for which latex does not know the hyphenation, you can manually tell it the possible hyphenation points:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\title{Title}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{aaa-aaaaa-aaaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaaa-aaaaaa-aaaaaa}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

Why doesn't Latex  hyphenate a word for me? The words aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa goes beyond the boundary like this.
\end{document}
```

[image]